# Why is there a borrow of a moved value when calling a method that takes self by value with an argument that also calls a method?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I ran into an issue that forces me to split a nice oneliner into a `{}` block with an intermediate `let`. The reason for this isn't clear to me at all. I was able to isolate the issue in this minimal example:

```
struct AB {
    a: u8,
    b: u8,
}

impl AB {
    fn foo(&self) -> String {
        String::from("foo")
    }
    fn bar(self, x: String) -> String {
        format!("{} - {} - {}!", x, self.a, self.b)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = AB { a: 3, b: 5 };
    let result = x.bar(x.foo());
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

I was under the impression that the arguments to the `bar` function would be evaluated *before* calling `bar`. `foo` borrows `x` during its execution, but when it returns its `String`, the borrow is finished, as `String` is not a reference bearing `x`'s lifetime. When `bar` gets called, `foo`'s borrow should be over.

However, the compiler disagrees:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `x`
  --> src/main.rs:17:24
   |
17 |     let result = x.bar(x.foo());
   |                  -     ^ value borrowed here after move
   |                  |
   |                  value moved here
   |
   = note: move occurs because `x` has type `AB`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I'm not disagreeing with the fact that `bar` indeed moves `x`. My issue is with the statement that `foo` borrows `x` *after* the move takes place.

A simple (but ugly) fix:

```
struct AB {
    a: u8,
    b: u8,
}

impl AB {
    fn foo(&self) -> String {
        String::from("foo")
    }
    fn bar(self, x: String) -> String {
        format!("{} - {} - {}!", x, self.a, self.b)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = AB { a: 3, b: 5 };
    let y = x.foo();
    let result = x.bar(y);
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

separating the assignment of `x.foo()` to an intermediate variable `y` compiles fine, confirming my expectation that the borrow is indeed over once `foo` returns, but why does this work? Is there something I don't understand about evaluation order? Why can't I get rid of the intermediate `let y` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Evaluation order, for the purpose of borrows, is from left to right.

This means that the subject of the `bar` call, the "move-out" mention of `x`, is considered before the "borrow" mention of `x` in the `foo` call, and therefore, the compiler considers the variable to have been moved from.

For the similar case where the outer mention is a mutable borrow, [RFC 2025](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2025-nested-method-calls.html) has been accepted as a solution, but hasn't been implemented yet. Unfortunately this RFC doesn't appear to cover your case, where the outer use is a move.

Comment: So the borrow-checker's evaluation order is different from real execution order?

Comment: @MathijsKwik The real execution order has to be roughly the same to avoid unsoundness, but unless your method call invokes a `deref()`, there's no way to tell.

Comment: I think part of my confusion comes from the sugar that is OOP-style method-syntax. `x(a,b,c)` looks like a function involving 3 arguments. The left-to-right evaluation makes sense there, but since `x` is "outside the parenthesis" I mistakenly counted it as "not part of the function call itself". But by indeed looking at it as `AB::bar(x, x.foo())` makes it clear.

Thanks

Comment: Why does this work, then? `let mut v = vec![0, 1, 2]; v.push(v.len());`

Comment: that's what the RFC is about. I do think my "outer-move" case can/should be handled similarly. If a bunch of borrows and a move of the same object are to be evaluated, it should be clear that the only order that might work, is by evaluating all borrows before the move. Of course if any of the borrows stick around (in a lifetime), it would still fail.

Comment: @MathijsKwik I don't think "evaluation order" is the right way to think about this: lifetimes are *inferred*, not evaluated. Two-phase borrowing fixes the `&mut` case by splitting the borrow into two with different lifetimes, but a move isn't a borrow and doesn't have a lifetime, so it's really quite different semantically. However, I agree that it seems like the `self`-taking case could also be handled in a similar way.

Comment: @trentcl *Two-phase borrowing fixes the `&mut` case by splitting the borrow into two with different lifetimes* Could you elaborate on which two sub-borrows the original `&mut v` borrow is split into? **PS:** I notice that while `v.push(v.len())` compiles, `Vec::push(&mut v, v.len())` doesn't. There must be some `Deref` magic behind the curtain.

Comment: @nalzok In two-phase borrowing (which, to be clear, is what happens in `v.push(v.len())`) a `&mut` borrow is treated initially as a shared borrow which is then "upgraded" into a full mutable borrow in order to call the function. I can't really do the concept any more justice than [the rustc dev guide](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/borrow_check/two_phase_borrows.html), which also confirms your suspicion there is something funny going on with `v.push`; however, it's not `Deref` this time, but autoref.