# Why can I not call FnMut twice in a line?

Tags: rust, reference, closures, borrow-checker, ownership

Taking example snippets from [here](https://fasterthanli.me/articles/a-half-hour-to-learn-rust): the following doesn't compile

```rust
fn foobar<F>(mut f: F)
    where F: FnMut(i32) -> i32
{
    println!("{}", f(f(2))); 
    // error: cannot borrow `f` as mutable more than once at a time
}

fn main() {
    foobar(|x| x * 2);
}
```

but this does

```
fn foobar<F>(mut f: F)
    where F: FnMut(i32) -> i32
{
    let tmp = f(2);
    println!("{}", f(tmp)); 
}
 
fn main() {
    foobar(|x| x * 2);
}
```

I don't understand why the first snippet is illegal: it's effectively the same as the second one, just written more concisely. More specifically, why must `f(f(2))` mutably borrow `f` twice? It can simply borrow the inner `f` to compute the value of `f(2)`, and then borrow the outer `f` and apply it to the value.

Comment: Pretty sure this is just a case the borrow-checker doesn't cover properly, its kinda similar to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55117392/why-is-there-a-borrow-of-a-moved-value-when-calling-a-method-that-takes-self-by)

Comment: yeah I agree this is not intuitive as it seems the same but the borrow checker here isn't going deep enough to realize what's going on. I do think imho that the outcome is better. `f(f(2))` isn't very nice and adding one of the values into a variable results in better readability. But again just a personal opinion.

Answer (score 17):

> More specifically, why must `f(f(2))` mutably borrow f twice?

The borrows here happen in the order of expression evaluation, and expression evaluation is always left-to-right, even when the expressions in question are trivial variable accesses. The expressions to be evaluated in this code are:

- `f(f(2))` is made up of two subexpressions: `f` and `f(2)`.

  1. Evaluate the function value, `f` (and borrow it as `&mut` because we're calling a `FnMut`).
  2. Evaluate the argument, `f(2)`.

     1. Evaluate the function value, `f`; **error because it's already borrowed.**
     2. Evaluate the argument, `2`.
     3. Call the borrow of `f` with the argument, `2`. This is the result of `f(2)`.
  3. Call the borrow of `f` with the argument, the result of evaluating `f(2)`. This is the result of `f(f(2))`

The borrow checker *could* soundly accept this case, but it would require the idea of recognizing that the first borrow *hasn't been used yet*, which isn't currently a thing in the borrow checker.