# Cannot borrow `b` as mutable more than once at a time without reference return value

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, mutable, borrow-checker

The below rust code has compilation error.

```rust
struct Builder;
impl Builder {
    pub fn add(&mut self, id: i32) -> i32 {
        id + 1
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut b = Builder;
    b.add(b.add(10));
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `b` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> examples/mutable_borrow_at_a_time.rs:10:11
   |
10 |     b.add(b.add(10));
   |     - --- ^ second mutable borrow occurs here
   |     | |
   |     | first borrow later used by call
   |     first mutable borrow occurs here
```

Unlike the question [Cannot borrow `x` as mutable more than once at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281155/cannot-borrow-x-as-mutable-more-than-once-at-a-time), `add` does not return any reference at all.

Unlike the question [Borrow errors for multiple borrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165686/borrow-errors-for-multiple-borrows), the return type is `i32` which has `'static` lifetime.

While the following code can be compiled without errors.

```rust
struct Builder;
impl Builder {
    pub fn add(&mut self, id: i32) -> i32 {
        id + 1
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut b = Builder;
    let x = b.add(10);
    b.add(x);
}
```

Anyway it is cumbersome to create a dummy variable `x` every time for a compound expression.

Comment: In this specific case, `self` does not need to be `mut`.

Comment: Does this answer your question [Why is there a borrow of a moved value when calling a method that takes self by value with an argument that also calls a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55117392/2189130) *"Evaluation order, for the purpose of borrows, is from left to right"* - you have to split it up

Comment: @jmb I just simplify my question, in my real code, `builder` holds a counter and increase the counter after dispatching  a unique id.

Comment: @kmdreko thanks, the question is quite similar to mine.

Answer (score 1):

First there will be a *mutable borrow* on the *outer* `b.add(...)` and then there will be an attempt to make a second *mutable borrow* on the *inner* `b.add()`. That is wonderfully explained & visualized by the compiler in the error message that you pasted:

```
|     b.add(b.add(10));
|     - --- ^ second mutable borrow occurs here
|     | |
|     | first borrow later used by call
|     first mutable borrow occurs here
```

This limitation might be removed at some point, but for now, that's how it works.

And for your specific example, as Jmb mentioned, you don't need `mut` at all, so this will work just fine:

```
struct Builder;
impl Builder {
    pub fn add(&self, id: i32) -> i32 {
        id + 1
    }
}

fn main() {
    let b = Builder;
    b.add(b.add(10));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are attempting to use the [builder pattern](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/creational/builder.html).

The difficulty stands in passing a `&mut` on the builder from call to call.
Each step in the chain should rather **consume** the previous state of the builder and emit a new state (like `add()` here).
Finally, the last step (`build()`) consumes the builder for the last time and emits instead the value we intended to build.

You might be worried about the performance cost of these multiple move/consume operations (instead of altering through a `&mut`), but when enabling optimizations, the compiler is able to look *through* these calls and can decide to do everything in place: a function only containing `Builder::new().add(10).add(20).build()` produces `mov eax, 30    ret`.

```rust
struct Builder {
    id: i32,
}

impl Builder {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Builder { id: 0 }
    }

    pub fn add(
        mut self,
        incr: i32,
    ) -> Self {
        self.id += incr;
        self
    }

    pub fn build(self) -> i32 {
        self.id
    }
}

fn main() {
    let id = Builder::new().add(10).add(20).build();
    println!("id={:?}", id);
}
```